cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
Problem
I encountered this issue while using zero_copy, as shown below:
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> programs/solot/src/state.rs:62:12
   |
62 | pub struct Peach {
   |            ^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `Peach` (64 bits)
   = note: target type: `state::_::{closure#0}::TypeWithoutPadding` (40 bits)

Can someone help me? Appreciate very much.
Relation Code
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct RipePeach {
    pub ripe_peach: [Peach; 3000],
}

#[zero_copy]
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Peach {
    pub peach_id: u32, // 4
    pub peach_type: u8, // 1
}

Relation toolchain version
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/star/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
solana

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.77.2 (25ef9e3d8 2024-04-09)

Cargo.toml dependencies
anchor-lang = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = {version = "0.29.0",features = ["metadata"]}
solana-program = { version = "1.18.11"}
bytemuck = { version = "1.15.0", features = ["derive", "min_const_generics"]}


This is a guess, since the error message is confusing, but you should try to make sure that your type aligns on an address of 1 using arrays, ie:
#[zero_copy]
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Peach {
    pub peach_id: [u8; 4], // 4
    pub peach_type: u8, // 1
}

Then there won't be any padding in your struct, so it should be easy to zero-copy deserialize it
